# google app engine free tier and cloud platform

Tags: google-app-engine

After few years, I was looking again at Google App Engine and bit confused about the structure now. It used to allow me to create a project and use it till the free quota, and then upgrade to a paid account.  Now, I created a project with a gmail account (not a google app account, but personal). On the [console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and project dashboard, I see a link say `signup for a free trial`. That is a 60 day trial for `Google Cloud Platform`. What is that? Can't I use app engine application forever and pay only if usage exceeds the free tier? or is it limited to 60 days now?

Thanks.

### Edit:

It says, after 60 days, `Your instances will be paused, and you'll have the option to upgrade to a paid account. You must upgrade within 30 days of your trial ending or we won’t be able to restore your instances.` So, my main concern is there a minimum payment required after the trial ends to run a small app (which previously can run in free quota). It let me create a project without creating an account for `google cloud platform`. so, do I really need to join or can run a app engine instance without joining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The free quota/tier still stands. The free trial gives you more goodies for a limited time. Mainly, you'll get a $300 credit for 60 days. This credit is only used when you exceed your free quota. [More info on the free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/).

Update: to respond to your edit, no, there is no minimum payment. Some services require that you have billing enabled (your credit card on file), but even then, you only pay after you exceed the quota.

Comment: +1 thanks I made a small edit. can you please comment about it. thanks again